# max function processing off lists an expected result[Python newbie)

Tags: python

I am converting some python code to another language
I am dealing with a construct that says

```
p=(4,5)
q=(4,27)
if(max(p,q):
     blah blah
```

Now I assume that because the first element of both lists is the same number i.e. 4 that max would use the 2nd value to work out which is the larger p or q.  I had assume the answer would that q is the larger,  but the answer I get back is that p is the larger.

Is this the correct way that things are designed to work i.e. only the first value is compare in this case i.e. the 4 which in the same in both p and q

Comment: `max(p, q)` returns `(4, 27)`. And `p < q` returns `True`. What do you mean `I get back is that p is the larger`?

Comment: If you used `if max(p, q): ...`, it doesn't mean `p` is larger than `q`, but larger value (either one of `p`, `q`) is not false value (empty string, 0, empty containers, ...).

Comment: BTW, you have unbalanced parentheses in `if(max(p,q):`. Also, there are no lists in your code. `(4,5)` and `(4,27)` are _tuples_.

Comment: Thanks guys that is what I needed to know